# How to quickly retrieve large array from MongoDB

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, express

I have one 500kb document in a MongoDB collection that looks like this, with the "Content" array having 5000 entries:

```
{
  "BookID": "120",
  "Content": ["The day was pretty good", .42], 
             ["The day was great!", .83],
             .....
}
```

Running a query from Node using Express takes too long: 500 - 5000ms

```
app.get('/sentences', function (req, res) {
  start = Date.now();
  db.collection('Sentences').find({ "BookID": "120"}).toArray(function (findErr, result) {
      if (findErr) throw findErr;
      console.log(Date.now() - start);
      res.send(result[0]);  
  });
}
```

Is there a proper way to store or query data like this and get fast query times, or should I use something other than MongoDB? Ultimately I want to store thousands of books like this, without the need for complex queries.

Comment: BookID field is number or string in database ?

Comment: BookID field is a string when I insert from Python. In the database I guess it is not a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up storing the data as JSON files in S3. Quicker and cheaper

Answer (score 0):

use [hint](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.hint/#cursor.hint) to improve query performance .

```
app.get('/sentences/:id', function (req, res) {
 var bookID=req.params.id

 start = Date.now();
      db.collection('Sentences')
     .find()
     .hint("BookID_"+bookID)
     .toArray(function (findErr, result) {
       if (findErr) throw findErr;
        console.log(Date.now() - start);
        res.send(result[0]);  
  });
}
```

Comment: That makes the code cleaner but does nothing to improve query time as there is only one document in the collection.

Answer (score 0):

> I assume that you've already indexed the collection(If not so, please
>   do that. It will make it a lot faster) and still the queries are slow.

As this is a direct query to fetch data( and not even complex search) it's hard to make it more faster with conventional methods. But depending upon your use cases, you can make it much faster,

> like caching the results with [Redis](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis).

Answer (score 0):

Use lean() in your query, if your are not going to perform any add, update, remove command on the output doc. Using lean will give the output in javascript and none of the mongoose commands would work on the result doc.
http://www.tothenew.com/blog/high-performance-find-query-using-lean-in-mongoose-2/

```
db.collection('Sentences').find({ "BookID": "120"}).lean().toArray(function (findErr, result) {
  if (findErr) throw findErr;
  console.log(Date.now() - start);
  res.send(result[0]);  
});
```

Comment: `lean()` is a Mongoose-thing, but OP isn't using it.